# detect if div is ontop other elements (visible in the viewport) with overflow:hidden

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

I'm adding a div at the bottom of a video inside an iframe. 
Generally I append the new Div to the iframe's parent and it's fine.
BUT, if some parent divs have some css like width:100% and overflow:hidden, it doesn't work and the div remains behind the iframe's video.

```
<style>
    .defaultPhoto{
        width: 434px;
        height: 278px;
       overflow: hidden;
    }
    .defaultPhoto .photo{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .wrapper{   background: red; }
</style>

<div class="defaultPhoto">
    <div class="photo">
        <iframe width="434" height="278" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/2xbgl7OJrg4"></iframe>
        <div class="wrapper" id="Div0" >test</div> 
    </div>    
</div>
```

This works:

http://jsfiddle.net/kav7b3os/87/

This NO:

http://jsfiddle.net/kav7b3os/70/

So, how can I be sure to put my new created div at the bottom of an iframe video and be sure it is visible in the viewport?

I used also the elementFromPoint to detect if the div is visible, with no luck.

Comment: i.e elementFromPoint, like here (it gives me IFRAME or HTML obj, instead of DIV):

http://jsfiddle.net/u51Lguyn/5/

Comment: Use `position: absolute; bottom: 0px; z-index: 10000;` on the wrapper. No guarantee that it will on top always.

Comment: No it doesn't work, I don't want it at the bottom of the page, I want it just under the video and it should flow with the rest of the document. http://jsfiddle.net/u51Lguyn/11/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a height on your defaultPhoto div of 278px and then inside this you have set the height of your photo div to 100% (i.e. 278px) then inside this, you set the height of your iFrame to 278px. So, the iFrame takes up the full height of the parent container - the full 100%. Therefore, if you don't allow overflow your new wrapper div can't be seen. The way to fix this, if you don't want to allow overflow is to increase the size of the defaultPhoto div. Depending on your requirements, you could do this with javascript at the point you add your new div.
Check out this fiddle which shows your layout with a larger defaultPhoto:
http://jsfiddle.net/fn5zancp/2/

```
.defaultPhoto{
  width: 434px;
  height: 318px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works in this particular case, but is there a way to be always sure/check that my created div is visible in the viewport at the bottom of the video? I mean, a general rule to apply in the css div itself, not guessing how the other elements of the pages are built?

Comment: No, there isn't any rule you could apply to the div that would solve this problem because the iFrame takes up all of the height and you are not allowing overflow. However, if the parent divs are always structured as above, you could use javascript to move up the DOM from your div and increase the size of the top parent in order to allow your div to fit.  Would that work for your situation?

Comment: Another possibility is that you add your div below the defaultPhoto div. I don't know what your constraints are, is that possible?

Comment: I'm developing a FF addon, so I have to deal with every pages that contains an iframe video. There are a lot of combinations of parents of the iframe and their css, that's the reason for a general rule. I thought I could 1) check every parent div for overlay:hidden and change it to visible, 2) check if the appended div is at the same top-left position as its parent: if so, append it on the parent.parent div. [continue...]

Comment: This could work well if the divs are empty, but if they contains other elements, I could change heavily the layout of the page, in that I could wrap the iframe and my div inside a wrapper div and attaching it on the original parent.parent div : it would change also the original position of the video... Instead, if I don't use the wrapper div, I could have my created div not just under the video.

Comment: without wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/u51Lguyn/22/ , with wrapper: http://jsfiddle.net/u51Lguyn/21/

Comment: If you don't know the structure and css of a page to which you will be adding your div then you are going to have to deal with a lot of complication. If it were me, I'd set up lots of different test scenarios and then see if I can find a way of testing for them in javascript and solving each one. I think there will be a fair amount of work in covering all possibilities.